# Home button in Matplotlib 2.1.0 navigation toolbar embeded in pyqt5 window, it no longer works correctly

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, python-3.6

I embedded a matplotlib in a window maked in qtdesigner, pyqt5. I have 3 files

The window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MplMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MplMainWindow):
        MplMainWindow.setObjectName("MplMainWindow")
        MplMainWindow.resize(628, 416)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MplMainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.mpl = MplWidgetTest(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.mpl.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.mpl.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.mpl.setObjectName("mpl")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.mpl, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(95, 16777215))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.buttonDrawDate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.buttonDrawDate.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
        self.buttonDrawDate.setObjectName("buttonDrawDate")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonDrawDate, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.buttonErase = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.buttonErase.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(75, 16777215))
        self.buttonErase.setObjectName("buttonErase")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonErase, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MplMainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MplMainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 628, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MplMainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MplMainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MplMainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MplMainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MplMainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MplMainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MplMainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MplMainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MplMainWindow", "GroupBox"))
        self.buttonDrawDate.setText(_translate("MplMainWindow", "Draw"))
        self.buttonErase.setText(_translate("MplMainWindow", "Erase"))

from mplwidgettest import MplWidgetTest
```

The Matplot widget class:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Class to represent the FigureCanvas widget"""
    def __init__(self):
        # setup Matplotlib Figure and Axis
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        # we define the widget as expandable
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # notify the system of updated policy
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
class MplWidgetTest(QWidget):
    """Widget defined in Qt Designer"""
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # initialization of Qt MainWindow widget
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # set the canvas to the Matplotlib widget
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        # create a NavigatioToolbar
        self.ntb=NavigationToolbar(self.canvas,self)
        # create a vertical box layout
        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        # add mpl widget to vertical box
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        # add NavigationToolBar to vertical box
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.ntb)
        # set the layout to th vertical box
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

And the main file that call others:

```
import sys
from IHMDrawDates import Ui_MplMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget
import numpy as np
import datetime


class DesignerMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MplMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DesignerMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # connect the signals with the slots
        self.buttonDrawDate.clicked.connect(self.drawDate)
        self.buttonErase.clicked.connect(self.eraseDate)
    def drawDate(self):
#        base = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
#        x = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(24)])
#        y = np.random.rand(len(x))
        x = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
        y = np.sin(x)
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot(x,y)
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.relim()
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.autoscale(True)
        self.mpl.canvas.draw()
    def eraseDate(self):
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.clear()
        self.mpl.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dmw = DesignerMainWindow()
    # show it
    dmw.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After update to matplotlib 2.1.0, the home button does not work correctly. It always return to the inicial clean axes. Example:

1.-Before click in drawing button:
[image]

2.-Click in draw button:
[image]

3.-Click in zoom:
[image]

4.-Click in home:
[image]

before the update, pressing the button HOME it returned to the image number 2, now with matplotlib 2.1.0 it returned to image 4. Any idea.

When I add:

```
def drawDate(self):
    x = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot(x,y)
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.relim()
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.autoscale(True)
    self.mpl.ntb.update()
    self.mpl.canvas.draw()

def eraseDate(self):
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.clear()
    self.mpl.ntb.update()
    self.mpl.canvas.draw()
```

Then occurs:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer to this question is given in this post, just for Tkinter, instead of PyQt: 
[NagivationToolbar fails when updating in Tkinter canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483551/nagivationtoolbar-fails-when-updating-in-tkinter-canvas)

The home button restores the initial state of the plot, which is usually the desired functionality of a home button.

Here you apparently want it to restore the state of the plot, after the button has clicked. This would be done by calling the toolbar's `update()` method.

In this case you'd add

```
self.mpl.ntb.update()
```

inside the `drawDate` method.

The method could then look like

```
def drawDate(self):
    x = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot(x,y)
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.relim()
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.autoscale(True)
    self.mpl.ntb.update()             # <-- add this
    #self.mpl.ntb.push_current()      #     and possibly this(?)
    self.mpl.canvas.draw()


def eraseDate(self):
    self.mpl.canvas.ax.clear()
    self.mpl.ntb.update()             # <-- add this
    #self.mpl.ntb.push_current()      #     and possibly this(?)
    self.mpl.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I add self.mpl.ntb.update() inside the drawDate method the HOME button, only return to the image that appear after you clic the zoom button, no to image that appear when you push the draw button. Any Idea. If is necesary I can edit the question and include images to explain this.

Comment: I don't know what could go wrong here, but I added some code to show what is meant here.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but This is still working badly,I will have to do a downgrade in every user that update to matplotlib 2.1.0 and add a warning indicating that it should not be updated to matplotlib 2.1.0. 
This is really annoying

Comment: What do you mean by "is working badly"?  Adding `self.mpl.ntb.update()` as shown above would revert the plot to the state number 2 from the question, right? I thought this is desired.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but do not return to image 2, this always returns to image 3.

Comment: I added a video on how it looks like for me when doing the changes as in this answer.

Comment: I added a video on how it looks like for me when doing the changes as in your answer, I reinstall Anaconda 5.0.1 for windows and the problem persist.

Comment: Which *exact*  version of matplotlib are you using? Is it 2.1.0, 2.1.1 or 2.1.2?

Comment: Matplotlib 2.1.0 this comes in the installer of the Anaconda3-5.0.1-Windows-x86_64

Comment: Ok, try with matplotlib 2.1.2 instead. According to [this thread](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9974) adding `self.mpl.ntb.push_current()` would help. I cannot confirm or falsify because for me the `self.mpl.ntb.update()` is enough.

Comment: This finally worked. I am very grateful. I add self.mpl.ntb.push_current() in drawDate and eraseDate method.